# How to document that a variable/an array/property contains a constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc

Sometimes, I need to use string or numeric value to decide between constructors, which all share the same class.

For example, right now I'm implementing reverse proxy that has several modes of proxy management: TCP, UDP and symethric UDP for now.

So I have an object:

```
const servers = {
    TCP: ProxyControllerTCP,
    UDP: ProxyControllerUDP,
    UDP_sym: UDPProxyBidirectional
};
```

The proxy will chose proper server module based on prior initialization request.

But how can I document that `servers` contains constructors of the `ProxyController` base class? I need that to work with Visual Studio 2017 intellisense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer consists of two things, both of which are hard to figure out.

### 1. Documenting value type for an object

This is the syntax to document what values does object contain:

```
/** @type {[key: string]: number} **/
const myObjOfNumbers = {};

// Visual studio hints number type, even though the value is not defined right now
const num = myObjOfNumbers["hello world"];
```

### 2. Defining a constructor type

This is more intuitive:

```
/** @type {new HTMLElement} **/
const test = null;
// Visual studio hints HTMLElement type, even though HTMLElement does not 
// have a public constructor
const elm = new test();
```

### By your powers combined:

```
/** @type {{[x:string]: new ProxyController}} **/
const servers = {
    TCP: ProxyControllerTCP,
    UDP: ProxyControllerUDP,
    UDP_sym: UDPProxyBidirectional
};
```

I can now use `new servers["UDP"]` and get a type hint for the base class.